# How would one distribute $a$ alike things of one kind and $b$ alike things of other kind and rest different things into groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multisets

My question is that how would one count the number of ways to distribute things from a group of different things and different groups of alike things (for e.g., $a$ alike things of one kind, $b$ alike things of separate same kind and so on..) into a specific number of groups containing say $n_1$ elements $n_2$ elements and so on. Kindly tell me if this distribution formula which you give me in the end changes if distribution is to be done in same groups i.e. $m$ groups containing same elements.

eg: say we have {a,a, b,b,b,b, c,d,e} and I want to divide them in groups of 3 elements each. Orientation of elements in a group does not matter ,ie order of elements in a group doesn't matter.
or say a simpler eg (which I have calculated)

is say you have {a,a,b,b,c,c} and you want to divide them in 3 groups of 2 elements each so the elements will be

{(a,a)(b,b)(c,c)}

{(a,a)(b,c)(b,c)}

{(a,b)(a,b)(c,c)}

{(a,b)(a,c)(b,c)}

{(a,c)(a,c)(b,b)}

these are the only 4 possibilities i repeat that the order of elements in the group does not matter ie (a,b) and (b,a) are one and same thing i am just looking for different arrangement.

Comment: Hard to decipher your question.  Please [1] Add a small example to perfectly illustrate the overall question that you are trying to ask. [2] Use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display any math in your question.

Comment: got it I will sure do

Comment: @user2661923 done kindly view it

Comment: I am unsure what the answer to your question is.  However, other mathSE reviewers, who know more Number Theory than I do, may be able to help.  Your editing has certainly made it easier for others to respond.

Comment: no problem brother thankyou so much for seeing this post!!!!